# Force Uploader to use iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo, uploader

I'm trying to setup an Uploader so that it works with IE9 as well as with more recent browsers.
So I thought I would force it to use the IFrame method:

```
            var fileButton = new Uploader({
                label: "UPLOAD",
                title: "Uploader un nouveau document",
                url: "theurl",
                force: 'iframe'
            }, mainForm.fileUploadNode);
```

Now I'm trying to return the result from the server as a JSON object in a textarea:

```
                String result = "<textarea>" + JsonUtils.jsonify(map) + "</textarea>";
```

This works fine on IE, but not on chrome for instance. As the default method is IFrame for IE and not for other browser, I suppose the IFrame method is not actually enforced.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've used a hack solve this problem: I test the Accept header to know how to encode the result.
[Followup question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670162/different-encoding-of-an-http-request-result-depending-on-the-accept-header)