# Different encoding of an HTTP request result, depending on the Accept header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dojo

I have a controller with a method to upload files, using, on the client side, the dojo Uploader class that supports ajax uploads for all browsers except IE, and uploads with an IFrame for IE.
The result is a JSON object, but when the IFrame mechanism is used, the JSON must be enclosed in a <textarea>:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/documentation/{appId:.+}/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadDocumentation(HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable String appId, @RequestParam("uploadedfile") MultipartFile file)
        throws Exception {
    // ....
    String json = JsonUtils.jsonify(map);
    if (accepts(request, "application/json")) {
                return json;
    } else if (accepts(request, "text/html")) {
        return "<textarea>" + json + "</textarea>";
    } else {
        throw new GinaException("Type de retour non supporté");
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to register this encoding mechanism in the framework, so that we would just have to return an object, and let the framework do the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I simply added a second method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/documentation/{appId:.+}/", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody    
public UploadResult uploadDocumentation(@PathVariable String appId,
         @RequestParam("uploadedfile") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    ...
    return new UploadResult(filename);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/documentation/{appId:.+}/", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces="text/html")
@ResponseBody    
public String uploadDocumentationIE(@PathVariable String appId,
        @RequestParam("uploadedfile") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    UploadResult obj = uploadDocumentation(appId, file);
    String json = JsonUtils.jsonify(obj);
    return "<textarea>" + json + "</textarea>";
}
```